# How to combine "If and vlookup" into 1 formula

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a formula that returns D+ if the student has a final mark >= 50 AND has a status of "Failed", otherwise return their grade using vLookup.

My Formula:

```
=IF(AND(M19 >= $D$6, N19 = "Failed"),"D+", ???
```

M19 points to the cell containing the student's final mark, and $D$6 refers to the benchmark score. I'm not really sure how to integrate vLookup into this formula, I know how to construct it on it's own, as such:

```
=VLOOKUP(M19, $D$3:$E$14, 2, TRUE)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with:  `=IF(AND(M19 >= $D$6, N19 = "Failed"),"D+",   VLOOKUP(M19, $D$3:$E$14, 2, TRUE)   )`

Comment: That is not reproducible with the info you shared in your question. Please read the section "Help others reproduce the problem" on [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem, but was unable to do so:

[image]

Row1 does show the formula that is used in that column. So cell `D5` contains the formula: `=IF(A5>3,"D+",VLOOKUP(3,$A$2:$A$6,1))`

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(M19 >= $D$6, N19 = "Failed"),"D+",INDEX($E$3:$E$14,MATCH(M19,$D$3:$D$14,0))),"")
```